# Hardcoding packages versions on docker image

Tags: linux, docker, version

Is a known way to track versions of installed packages on docker image? There is some example packages which I install

```
FROM docker.io/debian:bullseye
RUN   apt-get update && \
      apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates tar ... && \
      apt-get upgrade -y libc6
```

And now I have no control which package versions are used. Building from the same dockerfile twice might give different results. Things might suddenly start breaking and I don't know what the last working version of a library was.

I cannot hardocode a version eg

```
apt-get upgrade -y libc6=2.31-6
```

because the versions which are available in bullseye are constantly changing. And in the next few days `2.31-6` will be not available.

There is also no sense to use wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way  is to switch for `debian:buster`, which is currently latest stable release of Debian. Packages on stable releases are changed rarely (`bullseye` is unstable).

The hard way is to get packages\sources from additional dedicated repositories and then install or build them from source. For example https://deb.sury.org/ has any version of PHP. If you add it to `apt`, you can select which PHP you want to install.

Comment: But `debian:buster` has many many vulnerabilities even with high severity: CVE-2018-12886, CVE-2020-8285, CVE-2020-8286, CVE-2019-19449, CVE-2020-36158, CVE-2019-19814, CVE-2020-29569, CVE-2020-11725, CVE-2020-29661, CVE-2020-2937 and many more medium and low issues. 
Additional repository is good alternative for me. I hope I will find alter repos for all packages I need. Thank you.

Comment: @LancerX you should probably take a look at Ubuntu. It is based on Debian but it has frequent updates and security patches. It is better than using an unstable release.